# What is an idiomatic translation of "Are you in?"

Tags: translation

A friend recently asked me if I wanted to join a project he was working on. He ended with the sentence:

> Are you in?

It was a succinct way of ending and asking for an answer. It got me wondering, what would be an idiomatic translation of the expression in Korean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Verb `끼이다`](https://ko.dict.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6522100)

If the feelings you want the expression to have is not only just “doing the same thing” but also includes “getting in a group and **going with them**,” the closest one would be the one using [`끼다`](https://ko.dict.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6513000), which is a contraction of [`끼이다`](https://ko.dict.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6522100).

[`끼이다`](https://ko.dict.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6522100) originally means to get stuck in a crack or a narrow place. Its derived meanings are to get into a group, and to get involved in a scheme, a work, or a happening **by his own will**.

Note, it's not a slang, but is informal enough to sound slangy.

---

### Possible conversations

#### A convo with a close friend

> 야, 내가 지금 프로젝트 하나 생각해 둔 게 있거든. Hey, I'm thinking of a project right now.
>
> ……
>
> 너도 **낄래?** Want to join?

#### To someone you would be informal to

> 저희가 프로젝트를 하나 생각해 둔 게 있거든요. We're thinking of a project.
>
> ……
>
> 선배도 **끼실래요?** You want to join, senpai?

#### A polite suggestion to a stranger or an acquaintance

> 저희가 프로젝트를 하나 생각해 둔 게 있거든요. We're thinking of a project.
>
> ……
>
> 괜찮으시다면 같이 하시겠어요? Will you work with us, if you don't mind?

---

I don't know much about nuances of English expressions, so sorry for that.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In dictionary style Korean it's 너도 할 것이니? but usually 너도 할 거야? is used and it doesn't have any grammar problem and 너 낄 거냐? is okay with friends.

Comment: "Are you in?" carries the weight of asking for a commitment. I wonder if 너도 할것이니? does too? Or is it that more just like saying "Are you also going to do it?" in casual speech between friends?